# is there a way to set the HideSurroundingHtml value in ASP.MVC 2

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building a table of data like this

```
<% foreach (var person in Model.People)
{
%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= Html.ActionLink(accessory.Name, "EditPerson") %></td>
        <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(c => person.Name) %></td>
        <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(c => person.Age) %></td>
        <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(c => person.Budget)%></td>
    </tr>
<%} %>
```

I've created templates to override the defaults following [Brad Wilson's tutorial](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            TablePlaceholder.Visible = false;
        }
        else {
            Controls.Remove(Data);
            DataPlaceholder.Controls.Add(Data);
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="Data" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="TablePlaceholder">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10em;">
                <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="Label">
                        <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName() %>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="display-field">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="DataPlaceholder" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

When rendering the table I don't want to display the surrounding HTML, but I don't have a clue how to set the HideSurroundingHtml value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner and more clear way to do it would be like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [AdditionalMetadata("HideSurroundingHtml", true)]
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

And in your view:

```
bool hideSurroundingHtml = (this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("HideSurroundingHtml") ? (bool)this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["HideSurroundingHtml"] : false);

if (!hideSurroundingHtml)
{
    @:<div>
}

//Content.

if (!hideSurroundingHtml)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I still am not crazy about how clunky the HTML turns out with all the `if` statements you'd need but I think it's a pretty straightforward way of going about it.

Comment: Note that this technique creates and accesses an entry in the `AdditionalValues` dictionary and does not actually set the `HideSurroundingHtml` flag in `ModelMetadata` itself; unintuitively, the flag remains false.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [MSDN page on ModelMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.hidesurroundinghtml(VS.100).aspx):

> When this property is used with the
>   DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
>   model metadata provider, it is set to
>   true when both the
>   HiddenInputAttribute attribute is true
>   and the DisplayValue property is set
>   to false.

So you need to decorate your property in your model with this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```

I doesn't make any sense to me but it seems to work!

Comment: i'll have to try it, but from gut feeling I think that it is going to render with the hidden template and not the template I want.

Comment: @adriaanp This might cause it to use the `HiddenInput` template, but you can override that with the `UIHint` attribute on the same property.